# websocket clients: is node.js really faster than go (gorilla and gobwas)?

Tags: node.js, go, websocket

I am moving my websocket code from node.js to golang where I do a lot of processing on the data.  The critial issue for me is to read and process the data as quickly as possible.  On just reading the data and comparing node.js to the two golang solutions, I cannot get golang to be as fast as node.js.  In the benchmarks below, the golang-gobwas solution is 2.2 ms slower on average over 200k messages (faster in 22% of the cases), while gorilla is 1.8 ms slower (and faster in 23% of the cases).

The benchmark node.js code is:

```
"use strict"
const WebSocket   = require('ws')

var ws = new WebSocket("wss://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/ws")

ws.onopen = function(evt) { 
    hitbtc_marketnames().forEach( function (marketname) {
        var marketid = marketname.replace('/', '')
        send_args({ method: "subscribeOrderbook", params: {symbol: marketid}, id: 123}, ws)
        send_args({ method: "subscribeTrades", params: {symbol: marketid}, id: 124}, ws)
    })
}
ws.onerror = function(evt) { 
    throw('error')
}
ws.onclose = function(evt) {
    throw('connection closed')
}
ws.onmessage = function(evt) { 

    var data = JSON.parse(evt.data)
    var ts = Date.now() / 1000

    if (data != undefined && data.params != undefined && data.params.timestamp != undefined) {
        var delay = Date.now() - new Date(data.params.timestamp).getTime()
        console.log(data.params.symbol, ";", data.params.sequence, ";", data.params.timestamp, ";", delay, '; js ;', evt.data.length)
    }

}

function send_args (args, ws ) {
    var msg = JSON.stringify(args)
    console.log(Date.now(), ' send: '+msg)
    try {
        ws.send(msg)
    } catch(ex) {
        console.log(ex)
    }
}

function hitbtc_marketnames() {
    // return ['ETH/PAX']
    return ['ADA/BCH','ADA/BTC','ADA/ETH','ADA/USD','BCH/EURS','BNB/BTC','BNB/ETH','BNB/USD','BSV/BTC','BSV/USD','BTC/EURS','BTC/PAX','BTC/USD','BTC/USDC','BTG/BTC','BTG/ETH','BTG/USD','DASH/BCH','DASH/BTC','DASH/EOS','DASH/ETH','DASH/EURS','DASH/USD','DOGE/BTC','DOGE/ETH','DOGE/USD','EOS/BCH','EOS/BTC','EOS/ETH','EOS/EURS','EOS/PAX','EOS/USD','ETC/BCH','ETC/BTC','ETC/ETH','ETC/USD','ETH/BTC','ETH/EURS','ETH/PAX','ETH/USD','ETH/USDC','EURS/USD','HT/BTC','HT/USD','IOTA/BTC','IOTA/ETH','IOTA/USD','LEO/USD','LINK/BCH','LINK/BTC','LINK/ETH','LINK/USD','LTC/BCH','LTC/BTC','LTC/EOS','LTC/ETH','LTC/EURS','LTC/USD','NEO/BTC','NEO/EOS','NEO/ETH','NEO/EURS','NEO/USD','OMG/BCH','OMG/BTC','OMG/ETH','OMG/USD','QTUM/BTC','QTUM/ETH','QTUM/USD','TRX/BCH','TRX/BTC','TRX/EOS','TRX/ETH','TRX/USD','USD/PAX','USDT/USD','USD/USDC','XEM/BTC','XEM/ETH','XLM/BCH','XLM/BTC','XLM/ETH','XLM/USD','XMR/BCH','XMR/BTC','XMR/EOS','XMR/ETH','XMR/EURS','XMR/USD','XRP/BCH','XRP/BTC','XRP/EOS','XRP/ETH','XRP/EURS','XRP/USDT','XTZ/BTC','XTZ/ETH','XTZ/USD','ZEC/BCH','ZEC/BTC','ZEC/EOS','ZEC/ETH','ZEC/EURS','ZEC/USD']
}
```

The golang-gobwas solution is

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gobwas/ws"
    "github.com/gobwas/ws/wsutil"
    "log"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func hitbtc_marketname() []string {
    return []string{"ADA/BCH", "ADA/BTC", "ADA/ETH", "ADA/USD", "BCH/EURS", "BNB/BTC", "BNB/ETH", "BNB/USD", "BSV/BTC", "BSV/USD", "BTC/EURS", "BTC/PAX", "BTC/USD", "BTC/USDC", "BTG/BTC", "BTG/ETH", "BTG/USD", "DASH/BCH", "DASH/BTC", "DASH/EOS", "DASH/ETH", "DASH/EURS", "DASH/USD", "DOGE/BTC", "DOGE/ETH", "DOGE/USD", "EOS/BCH", "EOS/BTC", "EOS/ETH", "EOS/EURS", "EOS/PAX", "EOS/USD", "ETC/BCH", "ETC/BTC", "ETC/ETH", "ETC/USD", "ETH/BTC", "ETH/EURS", "ETH/PAX", "ETH/USD", "ETH/USDC", "EURS/USD", "HT/BTC", "HT/USD", "IOTA/BTC", "IOTA/ETH", "IOTA/USD", "LEO/USD", "LINK/BCH", "LINK/BTC", "LINK/ETH", "LINK/USD", "LTC/BCH", "LTC/BTC", "LTC/EOS", "LTC/ETH", "LTC/EURS", "LTC/USD", "NEO/BTC", "NEO/EOS", "NEO/ETH", "NEO/EURS", "NEO/USD", "OMG/BCH", "OMG/BTC", "OMG/ETH", "OMG/USD", "QTUM/BTC", "QTUM/ETH", "QTUM/USD", "TRX/BCH", "TRX/BTC", "TRX/EOS", "TRX/ETH", "TRX/USD", "USD/PAX", "USDT/USD", "USD/USDC", "XEM/BTC", "XEM/ETH", "XLM/BCH", "XLM/BTC", "XLM/ETH", "XLM/USD", "XMR/BCH", "XMR/BTC", "XMR/EOS", "XMR/ETH", "XMR/EURS", "XMR/USD", "XRP/BCH", "XRP/BTC", "XRP/EOS", "XRP/ETH", "XRP/EURS", "XRP/USDT", "XTZ/BTC", "XTZ/ETH", "XTZ/USD", "ZEC/BCH", "ZEC/BTC", "ZEC/EOS", "ZEC/ETH", "ZEC/EURS", "ZEC/USD"}
}

type messageReceived struct {
    Jsonrpc string
    Method  string
    Params  struct {
        Bid       []interface{}
        Ask       []interface{}
        Data      []interface{}
        Sequence  int64
        Symbol    string
        Timestamp string
    }
}

func main() {

    interrupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt)

    u := url.URL{Scheme: "wss", Host: "api.hitbtc.com", Path: "api/2/ws"}
    fmt.Println("connecting to", u.String())

    conn, _, _, err := ws.DefaultDialer.Dial(context.Background(), u.String())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer conn.Close()

    var bJson []byte

    for _, marketname := range hitbtc_marketname() {

        m := map[string]interface{}{
            "method": "subscribeOrderbook",
            "params": map[string]string{
                "symbol": strings.ReplaceAll(marketname, "/", ""),
            },
            "id": 123,
        }

        bJson, err = json.Marshal(m)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        err = wsutil.WriteClientMessage(conn, ws.OpText, bJson)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        m["method"] = "subscribeTrades"
        m["id"] = 124

        bJson, err = json.Marshal(m)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        err = wsutil.WriteClientMessage(conn, ws.OpText, bJson)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }

    go func() {

        for {

            var t time.Time
            var data messageReceived

            msg, _, err := wsutil.ReadServerData(conn)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            json.Unmarshal(msg, &data)

            if len(data.Params.Timestamp) > 0 {
                t, err = time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z", data.Params.Timestamp)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }
                fmt.Println(data.Params.Symbol, ";", data.Params.Sequence, ";", data.Params.Timestamp, ";", time.Now().Sub(t).Seconds()*1000, "; gobwas ;", len(msg))
            }
        }
    }()

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    for {
        select {
        case <-interrupt:
            log.Println("interrupt")
            select {
            case <-time.After(time.Second):
            }
            return
        }
    }

}
```

The golang-gorilla code is

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func hitbtc_marketname() []string {
    return []string{"ADA/BCH", "ADA/BTC", "ADA/ETH", "ADA/USD", "BCH/EURS", "BNB/BTC", "BNB/ETH", "BNB/USD", "BSV/BTC", "BSV/USD", "BTC/EURS", "BTC/PAX", "BTC/USD", "BTC/USDC", "BTG/BTC", "BTG/ETH", "BTG/USD", "DASH/BCH", "DASH/BTC", "DASH/EOS", "DASH/ETH", "DASH/EURS", "DASH/USD", "DOGE/BTC", "DOGE/ETH", "DOGE/USD", "EOS/BCH", "EOS/BTC", "EOS/ETH", "EOS/EURS", "EOS/PAX", "EOS/USD", "ETC/BCH", "ETC/BTC", "ETC/ETH", "ETC/USD", "ETH/BTC", "ETH/EURS", "ETH/PAX", "ETH/USD", "ETH/USDC", "EURS/USD", "HT/BTC", "HT/USD", "IOTA/BTC", "IOTA/ETH", "IOTA/USD", "LEO/USD", "LINK/BCH", "LINK/BTC", "LINK/ETH", "LINK/USD", "LTC/BCH", "LTC/BTC", "LTC/EOS", "LTC/ETH", "LTC/EURS", "LTC/USD", "NEO/BTC", "NEO/EOS", "NEO/ETH", "NEO/EURS", "NEO/USD", "OMG/BCH", "OMG/BTC", "OMG/ETH", "OMG/USD", "QTUM/BTC", "QTUM/ETH", "QTUM/USD", "TRX/BCH", "TRX/BTC", "TRX/EOS", "TRX/ETH", "TRX/USD", "USD/PAX", "USDT/USD", "USD/USDC", "XEM/BTC", "XEM/ETH", "XLM/BCH", "XLM/BTC", "XLM/ETH", "XLM/USD", "XMR/BCH", "XMR/BTC", "XMR/EOS", "XMR/ETH", "XMR/EURS", "XMR/USD", "XRP/BCH", "XRP/BTC", "XRP/EOS", "XRP/ETH", "XRP/EURS", "XRP/USDT", "XTZ/BTC", "XTZ/ETH", "XTZ/USD", "ZEC/BCH", "ZEC/BTC", "ZEC/EOS", "ZEC/ETH", "ZEC/EURS", "ZEC/USD"}
}

type messageReceived struct {
    Jsonrpc string
    Method  string
    Params  struct {
        Bid       []interface{}
        Ask       []interface{}
        Data      []interface{}
        Sequence  int64
        Symbol    string
        Timestamp string
    }
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    log.SetFlags(0)

    interrupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt)

    c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial("wss://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/ws", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("dial:", err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    done := make(chan struct{})

    for _, channel := range hitbtc_marketname() {

        m := map[string]interface{}{
            "method": "subscribeOrderbook",
            "params": map[string]string{
                "symbol": strings.ReplaceAll(channel, "/", ""),
            },
            "id": 123,
        }
        err = c.WriteJSON(m)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        m["method"] = "subscribeTrades"
        m["id"] = 124
        err = c.WriteJSON(m)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }

    }

    go func() {
        defer close(done)
        for {

            var t time.Time
            var data messageReceived

            err := c.ReadJSON(&data)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("error:", err)
                os.Exit(0)
            }

            if len(data.Params.Timestamp) > 0 {
                t, err = time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z", data.Params.Timestamp)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }
                fmt.Println(data.Params.Symbol, ";", data.Params.Sequence, ";", data.Params.Timestamp, ";", time.Now().Sub(t).Seconds()*1000, "; gorilla")
            }

        }
    }()

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            return
        case <-interrupt:
            log.Println("interrupt")
            select {
            case <-done:
            case <-time.After(time.Second):
            }
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Methodology: I output the strings of each snippet to terminal.  I am running the three solutions simultaneously and comparing the delay times message by message.  Everything run on a good linux server running the latest version of debian.

Is node.js really just **faster** than golang, or what am I missing?

Comment: Try to isolate the performance difference by measuring time to read message only.  Do not parse the JSON or write to stdout on each message.

Comment: thank you.  The messages are small, so the time to parse and output to stdout is on the order of 10 us

Comment: Also, take a look on easyjson generators. They are a simple generators without reflection, you may use no "encoding/json" but use pre-generated stuff. It's like 5x faster (e.g 1000ns with `yourObject.MarshallJSON()` instead of 5000ns with `json.Marshall()` call on benchmarks) Everything would be generated with comments and `go generate` calls - just put it into your Makefile or whatever you use for your automated builds. Want more? Take a look at google protobuf generators (its called `protoc`) Its way better json in terms of performance, but you may not change it easily to be bw/fw compatible

Comment: @simmi were you able to figure out more about why go version was slower? I am trying to choose b/w go and node.js for websockets server, and your insights can help me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Your code process all messages in the same goroutine.

That basically blocks new message receiving till previous message is processed.

Try this (gorilla) to see if that helps:

```golang
    go func() {

        for {
            msg, _, err := wsutil.ReadServerData(conn)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            // dedicated goroutine for message processing, unblocking current one
            go func() {
                var t time.Time
                var data messageReceived

                json.Unmarshal(msg, &data)

                if len(data.Params.Timestamp) > 0 {
                    t, err = time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z", data.Params.Timestamp)
                    if err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                    }
                    fmt.Println(data.Params.Symbol, ";", data.Params.Sequence, ";", data.Params.Timestamp, ";", time.Now().Sub(t).Seconds()*1000, "; gobwas ;", len(msg))
                }
            }()

        }
    }()
```

Comment: I think you are on the right track here. The nodejs code is definitely async, but as far as I can see, the Go implementation is blocking. Another thin to note is that WebSocket.send in node returns immediately, so the node version will asynchronously start responding while requests are still being sent. The Go version does all the sending first

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I have measured the impact, and this new gobwas version is on average 3.3 ms slower than my original version.  I would try to explain that by rare (average 250 msg/sec) and small (average <1k) messages vs the time to fire up a new go routine